# Overloaded operators from other .NET languages

Tags: f#

How does F# handle overloaded operators from other .NET languages.

For example, I am using a library where != has been overloaded to return a new instance of the object itself.

Eg.

```
Object newObject = a != b;
```

When I use the <> operator on the same object in F# a value of type bool is being returned.  What is the reason for this?  Shouldn't the overloaded operator be used?  If not, how can I extend these operator overloads to F#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most overloaded operators (+, *, etc.) can be called from F# without issue.  However, F#'s equality and comparison operators are not overloaded (F# uses structural equality instead), so you'll need to call your custom operator manually (e.g. `MyType.(<>)`).